# Can LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder work when autoRead is set to false

Tags: netty

I'm writing a proxy using netty 4 that has a `LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder` at the start of the pipeline. The proxy needs to decode the message before sending it on to the next server.

I've set `autoRead` to false and manually call `Channel.read()` when the previous write has completed, as in the proxy example.

It doesn't seem to work though, if a read doesn't contain a complete frame, the `LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder` swallows the read. My proxy handler doesn't get a chance to request the next read, so the server waits forever.

Is it possible to use `LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder` in a proxy the way I want to, or is there an alternative way to ensure that the proxy will only read a message when it can be written to the next server?

Comment: It should be possible... Please share your code

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here. This happened with netty 4.0.27. When the peer writer sends a single message longer than 1024 bytes, the reads hang immediately. This doesn't happen when I drop the LFBFDecoder, nor if AUTO_READ is true. My initChannel method:

```
final LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder dec = new LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(65535, 0, 2, 0, 2, true);
final LengthFieldPrepender prep = new LengthFieldPrepender(2);
channel.pipeline().addLast(prep);
channel.pipeline().addLast(new ByteArrayEncoder());
channel.pipeline().addLast(dec);
channel.pipeline().addLast(new ByteArrayDecoder());
channel.pipeline().addLast(readerHandler);
```

I expect having to reissue a read() only when a full message was received (in the channelRead() method).

As a workaround, I modified the LFBFDecoder by adding two reads in the decode() method, and it is working now.

```
 if (in.readableBytes() < lengthFieldEndOffset) {
            ctx.channel().read(); // HERE
            return null;
        }
```

and

```
// never overflows because it's less than maxFrameLength
        int frameLengthInt = (int) frameLength;
        if (in.readableBytes() < frameLengthInt) {
            ctx.channel().read(); // HERE
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: I verified today that this was fixed with the release 4.0.28. No workaround needed.